How can I hear the ATC communications with my instructor loud and clear in my headset
I am training with the DA40 TDI GARMIN 1000 FADEC aircraft, whenever me and my instructor talk to each other,it is loud and clear but when he speaks with ATC or ATC with him, it becomes quiet and unclear. I think it’s an issue with the intercom isolation but I’m not sure. Please can anyone help?

What radio and intercom? Sounds like the sidetone is turned way down.

Have you talked to your instructor about this? He should know how to configure the audio panel so you can hear. Learning to use the radio is part of your training. If you can't hear ATC you can't learn. Also, why is he doing all the radio calls? When I was learning, my instructor was coaching me while I was making most of the calls. He only stepped in if it was something unusual that he wanted.

Yes I did he said it’s just the way the aircraft is built, whoever uses the push to talk button has priority on hearing ATC ‍♂️

You could ask both ATC and your instructor to scream into their respective microphones instead

Generally you have separate volume controls for the intercom (you and you instructor) and the radios (between you and ATC). You should be able to adjust until they are to your liking. Separately, you will develop a skill that mentally mutes your instructor as soon as you hear the first "crackle" of a radio communication. This just takes time, but it will come. The more practice and air-time you get, the less busy and frantic things feel. This allows you time to sort out the finer points beyond just keeping the shiny side up. Good luck.

Check the volume on your radios. If those are low, then it’s not going to be loud and clear in your headset.  Your intercom volume is controlled By the lower knob on the G1000 Audio panel. Your COM radio volumes are controlled by the small knob on the upper right hand corner of both the PFD and MFD displays.
